# When tapping preview on editing an existing answer, the app crashes

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Post a question, tap edit, tap preview. Boom.

Version 0.1.25

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue. Could you provide your iPhone's OS and device model?

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the next build.  There was a bad assertion.